# Function-scoped constants in PHP

Tags: php

Is it possible to have constants in PHP that are function-scoped?

If not, what's the preferred alternative for the case where we need a constant inside a function (not a method)?

**EDIT**

My particular use case:

I have a function that works with a db. I'd like to store the table name (and potentially, other information that won't change, such as the field names) in a constant (vs just "hardcoding" it in the connection string). Other functions don't need to know about my table name.

Comment: a bit more information please

Comment: Most functions should be relatively short where setting a constant inside the function scope would be unnecessary. Can you explain more what you want to do?

Comment: How do *you* define Function vs Method?

Comment: @ficuscr: a method is inside a class.

Comment: It sounds like what you are looking for are probably http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php.

Comment: @datasage: no, those are class constants.

Comment: @abeln Yes they are, its the closest you will get to scoped constants. I am curious what kind of design would involve things like table name needing to be scoped in a function rather than a class which would make more sense.

Comment: @datasage: if my db access is happening through a function that is **not** inside a class, then wouldn't a function-scoped constant make sense?

Comment: from what you are talking "other function don't need to know about my table name", that a simple function scope variable, you don't need a constant. there is no way for other function to get the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can get what you want with Name Spaces if on a somewhat recent version of PHP.

Take a look at this page: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.nsconstants.php

```
<?php
namespace my\name; // see "Defining Namespaces" section

class MyClass {}
function myfunction() {}
const MYCONST = 1;

$a = new MyClass;
$c = new \my\name\MyClass; // see "Global Space" section

$a = strlen('hi'); // see "Using namespaces: fallback to global
               // function/constant" section

$d = namespace\MYCONST; // see "namespace operator and __NAMESPACE__
                    // constant" section
$d = __NAMESPACE__ . '\MYCONST';
echo constant($d); // see "Namespaces and dynamic language features" section
```